# Existence of weak solution in Sobolev space $W^{1,p}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $B\colon W^{1,p}\times W^{1,q}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ , $p>2$ where

$$B[u,v]=\int \left( Du \,Dv+ h u v \right)\, dx$$

where $h>0$. I am interested to prove

$$\sup_{\substack{v\in W^{1,q}\\ v \neq 0}}\frac{B[u,v]}{\|v\|_{W^{1,q}}}\geq C \|u\|_{W^{1,p}}$$

Would someone please give me some hint!

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that $$\sup_{\substack{v\in W^{1,q}\\ v \neq 0}}\frac{B[u,v]}{||v||_{W^{1,q}}} = \left( \int \left( |\nabla u|^p + h |u|^p \right)\, dx \right)^{1/p}.$$

Comment: How did you get this result?

Comment: Well, I did not compute. But it is known that $$\sup_{\|v\|_{L^q}=1} \int uv = \|u\|_{L^p}$$ whenever $u \in L^p$. Well, probably my formula is wrong, and should be $$\ldots = \|\nabla u\|_{L^p} + \|hu\|_{L^p}.$$

Comment: Do you have any reference (book,...) for this formula?

Comment: @user92228: Is $h$ constant? Otherwise I don't see why this would be true. If $h$ is constant I can provide a solution. I believe.

Comment: Actually, $h$ is a bounded non-negative function.

Comment: Why are you trying to prove this? Also, what is the relation between the title and your question?

Comment: I want to show this elliptic bilinear form has unique weak solution in $W^{1,p}$ (my case $p=3$) and I am using generalized version of Lax-Milgram theorem.

Comment: What is this generalized version? Can you post a link? I just want to see the hypothesis...

Comment: The actual general name is The Banach–Nečas–Babuška Theorem. In the case of Lax-Milgram theorem bilinear form is on a Hilbert space, but here it can be on a Banach space. And the condition which I posted is called inf-sup condition.

Comment: Can we assume that the domain is bounded?

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb{R}^4\backslash \{0\}$.

Comment: Unbounded domain... I can prove for a bounded domain, but for unbounded domains, no arguments applied in bounded domains works... Did you tried something, has some hint?

Comment: What can you prove in bounded domain? I suppose the prove won't be very different for unbounded domain. could you show me how you prove for bounded domain?

Comment: I am gonna write it as a answer, because it is too big for this space...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where you gonna post the answer?

Comment: Sorry, but I did some wrong calculations here. Have to think more...

Comment: As far as I remember, Lax-Milgram wants $B(u,u) \geq a \|u\|^2$.

Comment: @Siminore, This hypothesis is in the case where the domain space is the same.

Comment: @Tomás Sorry, you are right. I usually work on $H^1$...

Comment: @Shuhao Cao: you wrote a solution here yesterday, but it is not here right now. What happen to your solution?

Comment: I known that this doesn't fit into your assumptions, but I guess that you can't prove this. If $p=2=q$ (I repeat, you take $p>2$, but I suspect you can find counterexamples also for $p>2$, the left-hand side is $$\int |\nabla u|^2 + h |u|^2,$$ which cannot be controlled from below on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ by $\int |\nabla u|^2 + |u|^2$. The issue is that $\inf h =0$ is not excluded by your assumptions.

Comment: Is it necessary to have a solution only in $W^{1,p}$? If the right hand side $f$ is in $L^p$, then the strong solution theory would give you a solution in $W^{2,p}$.